# Can I force full screen mode for any application?

Tags: window-management

Is it possible to force fullscreen in any application in elementary OS? I use Vim in my everyday work, but I would like to use gVim, but I don't see a way to make gVim fullscreen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You definitely can for gVim. I think this works on most apps, including ones that don't have a full screen mode, for example System Settings.

Open up System Settings and click Keyboard and then check you are on the Shortcuts Tab and Windows is selected in the sidebar:

[image]

Then click on the "Disabled" text in line with the Toggle Full Screen and press a shortcut key of your choice.

I went for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> as it worked in gVim. You could go for something else, but I'd advise against <kbd>F11</kbd> - or any Function key.

[image]

Then you can easily toggle full screen on any app:

[image] [image]

Comment: Ohhh thanks man, I post this questions in several places and I didn't have an answer until now, thanks again.

Comment: Great ! any idea why there isn't any shortcut when installing the OS ? I mean it's a feature that nearly everyone uses, and I don't see a reason why not to put a shortcut on it